# What is the easiest way to get an int in a console app?

Tags: c, console, user-input

I want to process user input as an integer, but it seems as though C has no way to get an int from stdin. Is there a function to do this? How would I go about getting an int from the user?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;
scanf ("%d",&n);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 6):

`scanf()` is the answer, but you should certainly check the return value since many, many things can go wrong parsing numbers from external input...

```
int num, nitems;

nitems = scanf("%d", &num);
if (nitems == EOF) {
    /* Handle EOF/Failure */
} else if (nitems == 0) {
    /* Handle no match */
} else {
    printf("Got %d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: Mine number goes to negative or random sometimes, why is this?This is if my integer is big, still within 32 characters but still big

Comment: An integer is usually 2 bytes long. The leftmost bit is used to store the sign of the number (0 for positive, 1 for negative), so we're left with 15 bits for storing the number itself. Because of this, integers in C can range from -32768 (-2^15 or 1111111111111111) to 32768 (2^15 or 0111111111111111). When you enter a number larger than the largest possible value, the leftmost bit gets assigned a value and the integer no longer represents a value you were hoping for. If you want to enter bigger integers use `long int` or even 'long long int' as it can hold much bigger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `(f)scanf`, which has been sufficiently discussed by the other answers, there is also `atoi` and `strtol`, for cases when you already have read input into a string but want to convert it into an `int` or `long`.

```
char *line;
scanf("%s", line);

int i = atoi(line);  /* Array of chars TO Integer */

long l = strtol(line, NULL, 10);  /* STRing (base 10) TO Long */
                                  /* base can be between 2 and 36 inclusive */
```

`strtol` is recommended because it allows you to determine whether a number was successfully read or not (as opposed to `atoi`, which has no way to report any error, and will simply return 0 if it given garbage).

```
char *strs[] = {"not a number", "10 and stuff", "42"};
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(strs) / sizeof(*strs); i++) {
    char *end;
    long l = strtol(strs[i], &end, 10);
    if (end == line)
        printf("wasn't a number\n");
    else if (end[0] != '\0')
        printf("trailing characters after number %l: %s\n", l, end);
    else
        printf("happy, exact parse of %l\n", l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard library function **scanf** is used for formatted input:
%d      int        (the d is short for decimal)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int number;
  printf("Enter a number from 1 to 1000: ");

  scanf("%d",&number); 
  printf("Your number is %d\n",number);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    int i = 0;
    int k,j=10;

    i=scanf("%d%d%d",&j,&k,&i);
    printf("total values inputted %d\n",i);
    printf("The input values %d %d\n",j,k);

}
```

from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Console/Readintvaluefromconsole.htm)

Comment: This looks very suspicious, it both stores the result of scanf() in i, and reads a value into i at the same time. Not recommendable.