# How to ensure the consistency of the data type in C?

Tags: c, types

Let us suppose the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

How can I ensure that the data provided by the user is an integer (and not, let's say, a char)?

Is there any library for reading data from the user that ensures that?

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`? Or read in the user input as a string and then try to convert it (with error checking)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865284/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-an-int-in-a-console-app (answer by dwc)

Comment: Usually you don't care about the input format, you care about *valid inputs*. If `n` has to be between 1 and *N* then you test that, not if it contains characters. *Garbage in, garbage out* helps keep your code simple.

Comment: By "ensure", do you mean removing the user's ability to enter non-digits in the first place?  That's not within a program's power.

Comment: @JohnBollinger...By "ensure" I mean being able to identify when the user doesn't provide an integer value in the example and being able to deal with this situation in a suitable way.

Answer (score 0):

There's additional work you have to do around the `scanf` call.

First of all, `scanf` will return the number of successful conversions and assignments - in this case, you would expect `1` on success.  If there are no successful conversions and assignments, it will return `0`.  If there's an error on input, it will return `EOF`.

So, as a first pass, you'd do something like this:

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 )
  // input was not an integer or error on input
else
  // successful input, do something with n
```

By itself, this is not enough.

`%d` tells `scanf` to skip over leading whitespace, then read up to the first non-digit character.  If you enter `"abc"`, then there are no valid digit characters, `scanf` returns `0`, and `n` is unmodified.

However, if you enter a string like `"12c"`, then `"12"` will be read and converted, `n` will be assigned the value `12`, `scanf` will return `1`, and *`'c'` will be left in the input stream* to foul up the next read.  Ideally, you should reject that whole input.

There are a couple of ways around this.  You can peek at the character immediately following your input - if it's whitespace, then the input was valid:

```
char dummy;
int items_read = scanf( "%d%c", &n, &dummy );
```

If `items_read` is 2, that means `scanf` read *at least* one decimal digit character followed by a non decimal digit character.  If `dummy` contains a whitespace character, that means the input was a valid integer.  If `dummy` contains a non-whitespace character, then the user fatfingered a nondigit character on input (meaning the value in `n` shouldn't be trusted).  Either way, we need to push that dummy character back onto the input stream before continuing.

If `items_read` is 1, that means we read *at least* one decimal digit character followed by hitting EOF, so that means our input has to be a valid integer as well.

So, the test would look something like this:

```
if ( items_read == 2 && isspace( dummy ) || items_read == 1 )
{
  // do something with n
  if ( items_read == 2 )
    ungetc( dummy, stdin );
}
else
{
  // input was not an integer, or error on input
}
```

Alternately, you can read your input as a *string*, then use `strtol` to do the conversion:

```
char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH+1];
if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) ) // using fgets instead of scanf for this
{
  char *chk; // stores address of first character *not* converted
  long tmp = strtol( input, &chk, 0 ); // convert into a temporary
  if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )
  {
    // input is good, assign tmp to n
    if ( tmp <= INT_MAX && tmp >= INT_MIN )
      n = tmp;
    else
      // input was within range for long but not int
  }
  else
    // trailing non-digit character
}
```